# Connecting PPPOE DSL modem to server?

Tags: 10.04, server, pppoe

I'm setting up a transparent proxy/filter server, I've encountered many issues.

My Question.  With a PPPOE DSL modem how do I negotiate a connection from my server. 
I am putting the server between the modem and the router (now just a switch and wifi AP)

The router did the PPPOE login for me.

My modem can be put into the following modes.  PPPOE on modem, PPPOE on computer(router), & bridge.

I thought I could connect to the modem with a static IP with my 2nd NIC with the PPPOE on the modem.  This didn't seem to work.  For example the modem's ip is 192.168.0.1 so I set a static IP of 192.168.0.2  This has worked in the past to connect and configure the modem.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need your server up to do the pppoe authentication. Look at these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/installation-guide/hppa/pppoe.html). I think they will help you to do this,

Comment: Thanks txwikinger but that's a different scenario, that's installing over network with pppoe used at boot.

I'll try the pppoeconf command again.  Just not sure why it isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need the *pppoeconf* command.

Comment: tried the ppposeconf command, no go.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what failed with pppoeconf? It seems like that is the preferred method of configuring.. well.. pppoe.

Comment: This answer is a bit short on details. But it is still the best answer I found so far. By running `pppoeconf` I was able to get the PPP connection established and get IPv4 traffic through. But IPv6 is not working at all, and  the reason I wanted to use Ubuntu as PPPoE router in the first place is the lack of IPv6 support in the router I have been using previously.